# The tk window won't show even though there is a mainloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Even though there is a mainloop being called my tk window will not appear. The code used to work but as soon as I coded in the second function in the nums class there is no tk window. I would like for someone to point out the mistake instead of simply handing out the answer.
Can someone please help me fix this problem?
I use Python IDLE 3.8
Image:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o65WI.png
Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time
#number assignments
class nums:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=randint(1,100)
    def assignnewnums(oldnum1,oldnum2,lbltxt,lbl,answer):
        getans = answer.get()
        if(getans==str((oldnum1.value+oldnum2.value))):
           del(oldnum1)
           del(oldnum2)
           oldnum1=nums()
           oldnum2=nums()
           lbltxt="Correct!"
           lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
           time.sleep(5)
           lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum2.value,oldnum1.value)
           lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
        else:
            lbltxt="Wrong! Try Again!"
            lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
            time.sleep(3)
            lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum2.value,oldnum1.value)
            lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
a = nums()
b = nums()
#GUI startup
root = Tk()
#Label
title = Label(root, text="AddPrac", fg="dark blue")
title.pack()
#Question
questxt = "What is {} + {}".format(a.value,b.value)
ques = Label(root,text=questxt,fg="red")
ques.pack()
#UserAnswer
ans = Entry(root)
ans.pack()
#SubmitButton
enter = Button(root,text="Submit Answer!",fg="yellow",command=nums.assignnewnums(a,b,questxt,ques,ans))
enter.pack()
#GUI continued startup
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and the window does appear if you wait a few seconds.
This is due to the following offending code snippet:

```
command=nums.assignnewnums(a,b,questxt,ques,ans)
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. You were thinking of:

```
command=lambda: nums.assignnewnums(a, b, questxt, ques, ans)
```

The way your code is written now, it does not bind a callback to the button, but rather, calls- and executes the function (since you are invoking it explicitly), and attempts to bind the return value as a callback, which makes no sense. As a side effect of calling the function, the main thread sleeps (since `assignnewnums` uses `time.sleep`) for a bit before you reach `root.mainloop`.

Anytime you are binding a callback to a button, you want to provide a callable object - either just a function object, or if arguments are critical, a lambda or `functools.partial`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, is there a difference between when you would use a lambda over when you would use a functools.partial. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case, I would go with a `lambda`. I simply mentioned `functools.partial` as an example of other callable objects, but they're more specialized and I wouldn't worry about them for now.